# Add meta_type in custom sorting using woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using below code for custom sorting in woocommerce. This is working fine. The only thing is that I have to sort according to numbers. I have used `meta_type = UNSIGNED` but this is not working.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
   $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) :    apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

 if ( 'timer' == $orderby_value ) {
    $args['meta_key']   = '_auction_dates_to_time';
    $args['meta_type']  = 'UNSIGNED';
    $args['orderby']    = "meta_value";
    $args['order']      = 'ASC';
    $args['paged']      = $paged;
} 
if ( 'timer-desc' == $orderby_value ) {
    $args['meta_key']   = '_auction_dates_to_time';
    $args['meta_type']  = 'UNSIGNED';
    $args['orderby']    = "meta_value";
    $args['order']      = 'DESC';
    $args['paged']      = $paged;
 } 
return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
   $sortby['timer']   = 'Sort by Bid End Time: low to high';
   $sortby['timer-desc'] = 'Sort by Bid End Time: high to low';
   return $sortby;
}
```

Please HELP me on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs and the sources again.
Regardless of what you set `meta_type` to in the query (it's actually ignored, there's no such parameter in the docs), the actual data is still stored in the `wp_postmeta` table, `meta_value` column that has a `LONGTEXT` type.
Sorting on a `LONGTEXT` column is supposed to give you those results. That's the way [lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) works.

The *only* thing you can do is CAST that column to a numeric type thus telling the database it should do a numeric sort.
You do that with a custom SQL query, *or* use [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) built-in `WP_Query` feature:

> orderby (string | array) - Sort retrieved posts by parameter
>
> 'meta_value_num' - Order by numeric meta value (available with
>   Version 2.8). Also note that a 'meta_key=keyname' must also be present
>   in the query. This value allows for numerical sorting as noted above
>   in 'meta_value'.

Luckily woocommerce exposes exactly that by setting: `$args['orderby'] = "meta_value_num";` because `$args` is directly sent to `WP_Query`.

This [tells](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2261) `WP_Query` to *cast* `meta_value` to a numeric type (using `+0`):

```
case 'meta_value_num':
    $orderby = "$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value+0";
    break;
```