# WordPress order posts by 2 custom fields at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, posts

I want to **order the posts by 2 custom fields in the same call**. How is this possible?

This next code order successfully, but only by only 1 NUMBER custom field (not STRING):

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($q) {
    if (
        !is_admin() // Target only front end queries
        && $q->is_main_query() // Target the main query only
        && ($q->is_search() || $q->is_post_type_archive('data-base'))
    ) {
        $q->set('meta_key', 'custom_field_1');
        $q->set('order',    'DESC');
        $q->set('orderby',  'meta_value');
    }
});
```

---

**Update 1:**

Currently @Mohammed Yassine CHABLI's first answer works, but it doesn't sort by `number`, but by `String`. That means that "81" will come before "9", which is not good. Any solution for that?

---

**Resources that might help:**

[a more powerful order by in WordPress 4.0](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/)

[Add meta_type in custom sorting using woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459290/add-meta-type-in-custom-sorting-using-woocommerce)

Answer (score 4):

You need the WP way of providing an expression in the `ORDER BY`;

```
ORDER BY 0 + meta_key
```

That is, do something to meta_key to convert it into a numeric value.

Comment: Actually this makes a lot of sense, looking at the code: `meta_value_num` is basically `meta_value+0`: `case 'meta_value_num':  $orderby_clause = "{$primary_meta_query['alias']}.meta_value+0"; `

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

configure the meta query :

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'clause1' => array(
        'key'     => 'first key of your meta',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ),
    'clause2' => array(
        'key'     => 'second key of your meta',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ));

$q->set('meta_query', $meta_query);


$q->set('orderby',array( 
   'clause1'  => 'DESC', 
   'clause2'  => 'ASC' 
      )  
);
```

In case you want to sort in the same direction :

```
$q->set('orderby' =>'clause1 clause2',
        'order'   =>'ASC'
);
```

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately, the first method didn't work, and the second method gives me an error. Any other idea?

Comment: what's the error you get? can you show what have you tried?

Comment: I tried this and it didn't re-order:

`
        $q->set(
            'orderby',
            array(
                'first_order'  => 'ASC',
                'second_order'  => 'ASC',
                'third_order'  => 'ASC'
            )
        );
`

Comment: I think this is because it needs to be in the meta_query too, so it can know what "first_order" is. But I didn't manage to make it work

Comment: Your first answer works, but it doesn't sort by numbers, but by String. That means that "81" will come before "9", which is not good. How can we implement this answer to your answer? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38657/order-by-numeric-value-for-meta-value

Comment: Just a wild flyer: What happens if you replace `ASC` with `meta_value_num`?

Comment: Another wild thouht, what if you add `'type' => 'NUMERIC',` to the meta_query clause that defines the numeric field? for example : `'clause2' => array(
        'key'     => 'second key of your meta',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    )`

Answer (score 0):

A possible simple solution would be to format the text as if it were a number.

```
ORDER BY LPAD(meta_key, 5, '0')
```

Samples:

```
 9 = 00009
 81 = 00081
 777 = 00777
```

The weight on the performance of the query is to be evaluated.