# WordPress posts orderby meta value with strings and numbers

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, sql-order-by

I have a custom field (advanced custom field) called `custom_order` and I want WordPress to sort all posts by the field values.

**The `custom_order` field's values can be written in 3 ways:**

- **numbers only** (`3`, `400`, `6424`)
- **numbers, then strings** (`3A`, `3B`, `5000A`)
- **numbers, then strings, then numbers** (`3A1`, `3A2`, `401AZ1`, `9000A3`, `9000A1`)

More examples of `custom_order` values:

**Wanted order:**

`1, 2, 3, 3A, 3B, 3C, 3CA, 4, 400, 401, 401A, 401AZ, 401Z, 9000, 9000A, 9000A1, 9000A3`

**Conditions:**

- `3` should come before `200` (numeric order)
- `3` should come before `3A` (number and strings)
- `3A`  should come before `3A1` (numbers, strings, numbers)

---

**My try:**

My current code is sorting by numbers (condition 1), but ignores condition 2 and condition 3.

Therefore, my code gives me this order:

`1, 2, 3A, 3, 3C, 3B, 4` <-- all 3's are not ordered, which is bad

The code I'm using (in `functions.php`):

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($q) {
    if (
        !is_admin() // Target only front end queries
        && $q->is_main_query() // Target the main query only
        && ($q->is_search() || $q->is_post_type_archive('data-base'))
    ) {
        $q->set('meta_key', 'custom_order');
        $q->set('order',    'DESC');
        $q->set('orderby',  'meta_value_num');
    }
});
```

Comment: If you start by imagining how you would write a MySQL query that follows those rules, it becomes apparent pretty quickly that while it's possible, it would be difficult to do, and is not likely to be something that WordPress has built into it. It would be cool if you could provide a sort function to the query object, but there's nothing like that in the docs. I think you are going to have to sort your results after the query is run.

Comment: Hey Jerry, Thanks, I do believe that is possible through MySQL but my knowledge is limited in that area. I found a neat solution that is built into WordPress, see my answer below.

Comment: Maybe this hook? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_results/

Comment: I think it will be problematic on search results where there is pagination involved (because it will force to fetch all posts and that's a heavy task), however, this is a very cool hook! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

I found a neat solution!

```
$q->set(
    'meta_query',
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR', //**** Use AND or OR as per your required Where Clause
        'clause1' => array(
            'key'     => 'custom_order',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    )
);
$q->set(
    'orderby',
    array(
        'meta_value_num'  => 'ASC', // this reorders by numbers
        'meta_value'  => 'ASC', // this reorders by strings after sorting numbers
    )
);
```

Comment: I will test what you're saying right now and tell you my result, hold on

Comment: You could always pad the second number with a sufficient number of lead zeroes, so it's 1A022 and 1A003

Comment: You are right. This is not the best solution, but what you suggested with padding the second number did the trick! Awesome.

Comment: Or you could split the custom_order field into three, and order on them sequentially.

Comment: I have actually tried this before but run into problems where it sorted the fields by string and not numbers, resulting "8" to come after "41". here's my post on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708882/wordpress-order-posts-by-2-custom-fields-at-once/61708941?noredirect=1#comment109216252_61708941